# In ADS, what's the difference between a Parameter Sweep and Sweep Plan?

Tags: ads

I want to plot the transfer function/scattering parameter of a circuit with a varying capacitance.

Which one would I use, and what are their differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but nobody else has answered, so,

IIRC, a parameter sweep sweeps a single variable.

A sweep plan can sweep multiple variables in nested loops.

[More information](http://edadocs.software.keysight.com/display/ads2009/Parameter+Sweeps+and+Sweep+Plans).